# Kony Service call opstatus 1000 debug

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am making a simple service call in my Kony application and i can see that opstatus is returning back value as 1000, i have looked into the kony docs about this, Can anyone please help how to debug and make this working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your platform settings .

1000- Unknown Error while connecting (If the platform cannot differentiate between the various kinds of network errors, the platform reports this error code by default).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java SE version 1.6, try again with Java SE version 1.7.